# Why does my update $set code remove my entire document?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, set, mongodb-update

Help! 
I don't what am doing wrong, when I try to update an existing field using the $set method the entire document gets removed.

Can you kindly point out what I am doing wrong in my code:

```
recipientsDetails.update({_id: "GCYmFqZbaaYD7DvMZ"}, {$set: {paymentStatus: "Approved"}});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This code is correct.

Comment: You may therefore post the rest of the method, otherwise it will be impossible to solve this.

Comment: @Styx can you try running it in your browser console. It deletes even when I copy and paste and run it in my browser console.

Comment: @Jankapunkt `Template.paymentB2C.events({
  
  'click #approvePaymentButton'(event, instance) {

 var selectedRecipient = this._id;
 
 recipientsDetails.update({_id: selectedRecipient}, {$set: {paymentStatus: "Approved"}});
     
  
});
`

Comment: @SirBT I did run it in my `mongodb` console and it works as expected. How were you able to run it in your _browser_ console?

Comment: @Styx I use Google Chromium. In the settings I open More tools/Developer tools. Developer console opens up in the browser. I am able to run the javascript commands in the console

Comment: @SirBT Just to be sure, it works on client side as well: [Screenshot](https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/0P053A0r371P1T3P3L1m/Screen%20Shot%202017-09-11%20at%206.08.19%20PM.png)

Comment: @Styx Something very strange is happening. If I update $set a new field (that doesn't exist) in my document e.g. `recipientsDetails.update(
   { _id: "oePJnT6SREdoA9JNx" },
   { $set: { paymentStatus: "Approved"} }
)` instead of `recipientsDetails.update(
   { _id: "oePJnT6SREdoA9JNx" },
   { $set: { paymentStatusX: "Approved"} }
)` this works. I am even able to successfully. Any idea why this happening?

Comment: Is there any subscription listening to the changes of the doc, especially this field?

Comment: @SirBT You should update your question and add all relevant code that could affect this collection. Otherwise, we could only guess what is happening there.

Comment: @Jankapunkt Oh... thank you! You are a genius! Silly me for not figuring it out. YES It was definitely the subscription permitting only the paymentStatus = Pending in `recipientsDetails.find({paymentStatus:"Pending"});` to show, however whenever I updated to: paymentStatus = approved in `recipientsDetails.find({paymentStatus:"Approved"});` it stopped showing. I always assumed it was "removed", when it was merely hidden. Thanks once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is correct. It's likely that your publish function for `recipientsDetails` contains `recipientsDetails.find({paymentStatus: "Not Approved"})`. Naturally, once you update the document, the document will no longer satisfy that filtering query and the document vanish from the client.

Comment: Good guess, but in the answer @SirBT is saying that document is not vanishing from collection, but becomes replaced (instead of updating), so I don't think that's the reason. Anyway, we wouldn't know better until he provides additional information.

Comment: Turned out to be a great guess, nice work @DoctorPangloss

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct.Check you mongoDB using **[Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/)** tool.connect your local project with robomongo and update a document then check whether it is updated or not? If the record updated there is an issue with the publish or subscriptions